# Не отображается средее арифметическое

Tags: java, android

В общем, нужно выводить среднее арифметическое в activity 3

```
    public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

String[] countries = {"Urugay", "Paraguay", "Jamaica", "Peru", "Mexico"};
int[] population = {6770000, 2300000, 500000, 6310000, 7000000};
Button btnSubmit;
int sum;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    Map<String, Integer> countryData = new HashMap<>(countries.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
        countryData.put(countries[i], population[i]);
        }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        countryData.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + " -> " + value));
    }

    ListView countriesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.countriesList);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, countries);

            countriesList.setAdapter(adapter);

    sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < population.length; i++)
    {
        sum += population[i];
    }
    btnSubmit = findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main3Activity.class);
    intent.putExtra("average", sum);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Код из activity 3

```
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tvView;
int sum;
int defaultValue = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

    tvView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvView);

    Intent mIntent = getIntent();
    int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("average", 0);

    tvView.setText("Average: " + sum);
}
}
```

При выборе пользователем разных позиций в activtiy 3 отображается не среднее арифметическое этих позиций, а число 0.
Обьясние, что не так ?

Comment: А где в activity 3 у вас меняется значение `sum`? Укажите прям строчку

Comment: @ArchDemon, Нигде. activity 3 только для отображения числа. Разве еще что-то нужно ?

Comment: Ну тогда что вам не нравится? У вас в activity 3 значение `sum = 0`. Оно и выводится

Comment: @ArchDemon, а как тогда сделать правильно ?

Comment: Передать `sum` из activity 2 в activity 3. И не спрашивайте как это сделать. Учите язык, учите как работает android

Comment: @ArchDemon, так и делаю. Я же сюда и написал, чтобы подсазали хоть в каком направлении искать

Comment: У Вас не логики проверки выбранных позиций и считаете Вы сумму всех элементов, а не среднее.

Comment: @ArchDemon Где в активити 3 sum = 0?

Comment: @Эникейщик, если полю явно не присвоено значение, то неявно (при компиляции) ему присваивается нуль.

Answer (score 0):

Вы получили значение из интента в переменную `intValue` - её и выводите в `TextView`:

```
  int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("average", 0);
  tvView.setText("Average: " + intValue);
```

или получайте значение в `sum`:

```
  sum = mIntent.getIntExtra("average", 0);
  tvView.setText("Average: " + sum);
```